# constexpr base case not considered during compilation

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr

I was trying out the constexpr functions and stumbled upon the below example of implementing Fibonacci numbers

There is no logical difference between fibon2 and fibon1 but I still get the compilation error of exceeding template initializations for the fibon1.

What i'm missing here?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template <int32_t x>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
constexpr int32_t fibon2() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  if constexpr (x == 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  else if constexpr (x == 1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  else if constexpr (x == 2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    return fibon2<x - 1>() + fibon2<x - 2>();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
template <int32_t x>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
constexpr int32_t fibon1() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  if constexpr (x == 0) return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  if constexpr (x == 1) return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  if constexpr (x == 2) return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  return fibon1<x - 1>() + fibon1<x - 2>();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
int32_t fibon3(int32_t x) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  if (x == 1) return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  if (x == 2) return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  return fibon3(x - 1) + fibon3(x - 2);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
int main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  
  std::cout << fibon3(2) << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  std::cout << fibon2<2>() << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  std::cout << fibon1<2>() << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}
```

Comment: *"There is no logical difference..."* Yes there is.

Comment: your Fibonacci sequence is wrong. You are returning `1` to often (3 times in a row).

Answer (score 3):

The return in fibon1 is not under constexpr and thus has to be compiled regardless of the template argument provided.

Clang show this nicely: https://godbolt.org/z/577f15Kv1

If you put the return inside its own `if constexpr` then your fibon1 [will compile](https://godbolt.org/z/c4jd119ea):

```
template <int32_t x>
constexpr int32_t fibon1() {
  if constexpr (x == 0) return 1; 
  if constexpr (x == 1) return 1;
  if constexpr (x == 2) return 1;
  if constexpr (x > 2)
      return fibon1<x - 1>() + fibon1<x - 2>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The last `return` in `fibon2` is in a *constexpr-if* even though there's only an `else` there. It's the same as if you'd made it:

```
  else if constexpr (x == 2)
    return 1;
  else if constexpr(true)                      // <- like this
    return fibon2<x - 1>() + fibon2<x - 2>();
```

That's not the case in `fibon1` which is why it fails. If you want a freestanding `if constexpr` for it, then

```cpp
template <int32_t x>
constexpr int32_t fibon1() {
  if constexpr (x == 0) return 1; // shouldn't this be 0 ?
  if constexpr (x == 1) return 1; 
  if constexpr (x == 2) return 1; // this doesn't seem correct if fibon1<0> => 1

  // added constexpr-if:
  if constexpr (x < 0 || x > 2) return fibon1<x - 1>() + fibon1<x - 2>();
}
```

Note that the above will fail if you supply a negative value as a template parameter as it will never reach one of your terminating conditions. Either the recursion will be to deep or you'll get a signed integer overflow. If you instead want symmetry around 0, you can simply negate the template parameter and return value in case the template parameter is negative:

```cpp
template <int32_t x>
constexpr int32_t fibon1() {
    if constexpr (x < 0)
        return -fibon1<-x>();            // like this
    else if constexpr (x == 0 || x == 1) // assuming you want 0 for input 0
        return x;
    else
        return fibon1<x - 1>() + fibon1<x - 2>();
}
```